# iOS, margin on custom cells different in header than row, with autolayout?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I have an issue. I'm using a nib file for my table rows and the same nib for the section header. I'm also using auto layout on my custom cell.

Although I'm using different text and colors etc.

The idea being, that I can align columns etc.

However, the section header seems to wider than the cells, although the background seems full width.

I've tried various things to set the width, thinking it was being set differently, with a margin.

Here's my code....

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:
   (NSInteger)section 
{
    CGFloat w = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    HeaderSectionReportView *customHeaderView = [[HeaderSectionReportView alloc] 
         initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, w, 20.0) ....

    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ReportCell" 
         owner:self options:nil];
    ReportCell *customView  = (ReportCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];

    customView.descriptionValue.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    //snip
    customView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, w,customView.frame.size.height);
    [customHeaderView addSubview:customView];
    return customHeaderView;
}
```

//

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ReportCell";
    ReportCell *cell = (ReportCell *) [tableView 
         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
            loadNibNamed:@"ReportCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                cell = ((ReportCell *) currentObject);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    CGFloat w = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    cell.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, w,cell.frame.size.height);    
    cell.descriptionValue.text = desc;
}
```

Also here's my autolayout constraints
[image]

Comment: Try setting constaints without checking "constrain to margins" button from the "pin" menu from bottom.

Comment: Happy to hear that ! I am not sure If I must add it as an answer or not?

Answer (score 0):

The width of the header and of the cells is handled by the `tableView`. So setting `cell.frame` will not make any difference.

Therefore, your constraints for the cell seem to be a bit off. They should all be set to 0 and without any margin (disable/untick Relative to margin).

[image]

Hope this fixes your problem. Let me know if you need more help